# Three.js: Import and use 3d models

Tags: javascript, import, model, 3d, three.js

**Hello!**
I have searched ALOT about this on the web but havnt got anything that is working.
My question is: HOW do I use 3d models like collada, stl, obj, AND MOVE it with example `model.position.rotation=10;`?

Whitch is the easiest way of importing models in these formats? I only need one format to import to my three.js code.

**Tnx!**

Answer (score 1):

I always convert my .obj files to JSON and then load them into Three.js.
For that conversion I use [convert_obj_three.py](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py) script. You just need to run it and it will do all the work with the conversion.

And for the loading part, you can do this (with some examples how to manipulate the mesh):

```
function addMapMesh()
        {
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load("convertedFile.js", function(geometry){

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(geometry.materials));

                mesh.position.x -= 5.0;
                mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 0.05;
                mesh.rotation.x = .25*Math.PI;
                scene.add(mesh);

                //make sure mesh is loaded before renderering
                loadRestOfScene()
            });             
        }
```

Comment: Do yu think you can explain where to put it and use it? I have tried but I cant get it to work. :( Things like: Should i put in something for 'geometry' and what do you mean by 'loadrestofscene'? Sry im new to three.js :P

Comment: looks good in your code, what seems to be the problem? Is it rotated or not?

Answer (score 0):

can't say much about how to move, rotate or manipulate modells using Three.js, but I remember there were a few converter-scripts and some exporter-scripts for Blender to get different 3D-Modell-types into Three.js.

[This link](http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/58690562825/external-models-in-three-js) might help you. It provides Links to converter-scripts and even shows a rotation in the example code!